# How to access a block's owner

Tags: ruby

I have built a 10x10 matrix in ruby using

```
Matrix.build(10, 10) do 
  nil 
end.each_with_index do |e, r, c|
  # how do I get the Matrix object
end
```

As I loop over each element I need to know what's currently in the adjacent items in the matrix. How can I get the entire Matrix object from within the block? Is there a meta variable or method that I'm not aware of?

Comment: This is pretty contrived... Why can't you just assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with [`tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-tap):

```
Matrix.build(10, 10) do 
  nil 
end.tap do |matrix|
  matrix.each_with_index do |e, r, c|
    # do_stuff
  end
end
```

However, it is generally more readable and more idiomatic to assign the intermediate value to a variable and simply use that like [Marek suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21148728/50742) rather than make your message chain even longer. `tap` is rarely used outside of a few very specific cases because it confers little to no benefit and hampers readability.

Answer (score 3):

You can divide your code and assign new `Matrix` instance to variable at first:

```
matrix = Matrix.build(10, 10)
```

and then, you can call `each_with_index` on it and (because block is closure) use `matrix` variable inside block passed to this method.

Comment: What if it wasn't assigned to a variable yet and I called it in a chained manor (I've updated my question)?

Answer (score 1):

I would then tell you to do this as below :

```
Matrix.build(10, 10) do 
  nil 
end.instance_eval do
  each_with_index do |e, r, c|
    # self will automatically be set as the object on which each_with_index
    # called. Now you can use that object inside here as per your wish.
  end
end
```

See the documentation of [`BasicObject#instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval)